# Failed to transform artifact xxx.aar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetifier

Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Failed to transform artifact 'xxx.aar (project :xxx)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}
>   Execution failed for JetifyTransform: G:\android studio e\ChainStore-ManagementApp\chainstore-managmentApp\xxx\xxx.aar.
>   Failed to transform 'G:\android studio e\ChainStore-ManagementApp\chainstore-managmentApp\xxx\xxx.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: 5. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

Comment: found any solution on this?

Comment: used android.enableJetifier=false , but most be change library used.